# Delete everything after characters * or # or & in text file with GREP

Tags: text, grep

I have text file like this:

```
word1    & wordff 39 0: sgfdgggg, sgdgsd
word23   & sgfdgsdgsdgdg 44 0: sgdggfg, sfgdgdg
word45   *
```

And I need this:

```
word1    & 
word23   & 
word45   *
```

How can I do it in GREP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -Eo '.*?[&*#]'
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "word1    & wordff 39 0: sgfdgggg, sgdgsd
word23   & sgfdgsdgsdgdg 44 0: sgdggfg, sfgdgdg
word45   *"|grep -Eo '.*?[&*#]'
word1    &
word23   &
word45   *
```

Comment: +1 Brilliant. Does the `.` refer to the text we want to keep?

Comment: @fedorqui the matched part with the regex is the text we want to keep

Comment: `.` means "any character".  `*` means "zero or more of".  `.*` means "zero or more of any character".  I suggest googling for "regex tutorial" and digging into their capabilities.